# Equidimensionality under base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, change-of-basis

Let $X$ be a projective variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$; by taking integer coefficients, we can suppose that the variety is defined over the integers. We consider now the variety $X_p=X\times_{\mathbb{Z}}\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$, where $p$ is prime.
Once we prove the equidimensionality of $X_p$, can we say something about the equidimensionality of $X$?

We have equidimensionality on the closure of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$, from Hartshorne, exercice 3.20, Chapter II. I would also say that, if $X$ is *not* equidimensional,
then the same should hold for $X_p$, except for a finite number of $p$'s. Is it true?

Is there a way to prove for which $p$'s $X_p$ is equidimensional even if $X$ is not? Maybe an upper bound. I suppose it could depend on the coefficients of the defining equations for $X$ and on the degree of these equations, for example if $X$ is cut by quadrics, cubics...